# B-Splines of degree 1, 2 and 3

Tags: numerical-methods, spline

The basis functions for **linear** B-splines are:
\begin{equation*}
     \begin{aligned}
      & B_0(u) = (1-u)\\
      & B_1(u) = u.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

For **quadratic** B-plines:
\begin{equation*}
     \begin{aligned}
      & B_0(u) = u^2/2\\
      & B_1(u) = (-2u^2+2u+1)/2\\
      & B_2(u) = (u^2-2u+1)/2.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

For **cubic** B-splines:
\begin{equation*}
     \begin{aligned}
      & B_0(u) = (1-u)^3/6\\
      & B_1(u) = (3u^3 - 6u^2+4)/6\\
      & B_2(u) = (-3u^3 +3u^2+3u+1)/6\\
      & B_3(u) = u^3/6.
      \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Can anyone please explain how are these forms derived for the basis functions given the order of the B-splines?

Comment: What is your definition of a B-spline?

Comment: \begin{equation}
{\bf u}(\mathbf{x}) = \sum^1_{l=0} \sum^1_{m=0} \sum^1_{n=0} B_l(u) B_m(v)B_n(w) \phi_{i+l,j+m,k+n},
\end{equation}     In case of linear

Comment: \begin{equation}
{\bf u}(\mathbf{x}) = \sum^3_{l=0} \sum^3_{m=0} \sum^3_{n=0} B_l(u) B_m(v)B_n(w) \phi_{i+l,j+m,k+n},
\end{equation}
where $i = \lfloor \frac{x}{n_x}\rfloor-1$, $j = \lfloor \frac{y}{n_y}\rfloor-1$, $k= \lfloor \frac{z}{n_z}\rfloor -1$, $u = x/n_x - \lfloor \frac{x}{n_x}\rfloor$, $v = y/n_y -\lfloor \frac{y}{n_y}\rfloor$, $w = z/n_z - \lfloor \frac{z}{n_z}\rfloor$. $B_l(u)$ are the uniform B-spline basis functions evaluated at $u$.

Comment: hm ... and how are the basis functions defined?

Comment: As I told you in my first post. That's why I am wondering how they derived those basis functions

Comment: usually the basis functions are defined iteratively, like $k$ time convolutions of the indicator of $[0,1)$ with itself, or as non zero B-spline with minimal support. There are many recursion formulae.